# Joining on factor NA results in unexpected result

Tags: r, data.table

I just came across a strange behaviour when joining 2 data.tables, where a NA in a factor(-key) is involved:

```
# unexpeced
A<-data.table(a=factor(c("a",NA)), b=c(4, 5), key="a")
B<-data.table(c=c("a","b","c"), d=c(7, 8, 9), key="c")
A[B, dJoin:=i.d]

    a b dJoin
1: NA 5     9
2:  a 4     7
```

but I expected:

```
#expected
A<-data.table(a=c("a", NA), b=c(4, 5), key="a")
B<-data.table(c=c("a","b","c"), d=c(7, 8, 9), key="c")
A[B, dJoin:=i.d]

    a b dJoin
1: NA 5    NA
2:  a 4     7
```

Comment: Fixed in devel version, [#945](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/945). Try it with [v1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

Comment: Unfortunately computer at work does not allow to install from github. Is there a new 1.9.5 binary available somewhere. Or can I create the binary myself on another computer. If yes, is there a tutorial available to do that?

Comment: One way: [Go here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table). Download the zip file. Extract it. Then from terminal do: `R CMD INSTALL <directory>`..